# How to integrate examples with Doxygen?

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I documented all of my classes and now I want to integrate an example of how to use these classes. How do I do that?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can put example source code in a special path defined in the doxygen config under `EXAMPLE_PATH`, and then insert examples with the `@example` tag.

Doxygen will then generate an extra page containing the source of the example. It will also set a link to it from the class documentation containing the example tag.

Alternatively if you want to use small code snippets you can insert them with `@code ... @endcode`

The documentation for this is here:
[doxygen documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdexample)?

Comment: Yes I did that but the .cpp-files in the extra page are empty :/

Comment: hmmm does doxygen give any warning or error?

Comment: No. I included the example files in the INPUT tag and in the tag EXAMPLE_PATH the files that have the tag \example...dont know whats the fault

Comment: Do I have to use a special tag in the example cpp-files?

Comment: you may need to swap it. I will give an example: You have all source code in `myproject/src`, examples (which are just commented source code) in `myproject/examples` and extra documentation files (which may use examples) in `myproject/doc`. In the config, INPUT will need `myproject/src` and `myproject/doc`. EXAMPLE_PATH should be set to `myproject/examples`.

Comment: I got it...I forgot to add the example cpp-files to the EXAMPLE_PATH^^

Comment: I find it hard to follow their documentation. Too many words for a quick question/answer. I just opened SO and here we go! Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

Another way of doing it is to use the `\snippet` command.

- In your header file write something like:

> ```
> \section ex1 Example
> \snippet path_to_test_class/TestClass.cpp TestClass example
> \section ex2 Expected output
> \snippet path_to_test_class/TestClass.cpp TestClass expected output
> ```

- In the TestClass.cpp file, have something like:

> ```
>  //! [OptimizeSpeedOnTrackTest example]
>  Class c;
>  const double res = c.do_something();
>  //! [OptimizeSpeedOnTrackTest example]
>  //! [OptimizeSpeedOnTrackTest expected output]
>  ASSERT_DOUBLE_EQ(5,res);
>  //! [OptimizeSpeedOnTrackTest expected output]
> ```

`path_to_test_class` must be in your EXAMPLE_PATH.

This gives you the following:

- Your examples aren't just there for documentation: they provide test coverage as well
- Your test runner (& your compiler) give you the insurance that your examples actually compile & run
- It fits in pretty nicely in a TDD workflow

Comment: Using \snippet is just what I need. I've found that I get an empty box with no code whenever I include a \brief description on the element I want to attach a \snippet to.

Comment: A-ha! but using a \section to add a title allows me to include the \brief too.

Comment: In TestClass.cpp the comments must match the snippets, e.g. `// [TestClass Example]`

Answer (score 2):

I had some errors using @example to include the example file in the documentation.  This is the workaround I used.

Place `examplefile.cs` in a folder/project specifically for example code.
Place that folder in the Doxygen `EXCLUDE` list (Expert->Input->EXCLUDEin Doxygen GUI frontend) and in the `EXAMPLE_PATH` (Expert->Input->EXAMPLE_PATH in Doxygen GUI frontend)

Place this code block somewhere in a documented file (I put it in the file the example is for.)

```
/** @example examplefile.cs
 * A description of the example file, causes the example file to show up in 
 * Examples */
```

This causes the file to show up under Examples in the Doxygen menu, but not show up as a class/file in your project.

Then document your class/function:

```
/** @brief MyClass does something
 * @details I have something more long winded to say about it.  See example 
 * in examplefile.cs: @include examplefile.cs */
```

This causes the example file to print out in it's entirety in the documentation of MyClass.

Answer (score 1):

1. add a way to doxyfile
   `EXAMPLE_PATH = dir_example \`
2. can connect all of the examples in the same file such example_list.h
   and include it in doxyfile
    `INPUT = example_list.h \`

(language - Russian)
http://www.scale-tech.ru/SimBookmaker/doc/html/examples__list_8h_source.html
and 
http://www.scale-tech.ru/SimBookmaker/doc/html/examples.html